# JMeter Nested Variable Reference with JDBC Resultset Variable and Counter Variable

Tags: jdbc, httprequest, jmeter, httpresponse, database-testing

I need to query a MYSQL Database for a list of siteIDs and siteURLs. I've specified these names in the JDBC Request's Variable Name field.

Then I created a ForEach Logic Controller to cycle through the siteURLs ${siteURL_1} till the last record from the result as such:

```
Input Variable Prefix: siteURL
Start Index: 0
End Index: 40
Output Variable Name: newSiteURL
```

Then I use this in the HTTP Request's Path field as:

```
${newSiteURL}
```

This works fine and the HTTP requests are going through.

Now, I want to name the HTTP Requests properly so that they are indexed better.
For that, I decided to use the siteID field from the result set.

To do that, I created a counter variable as such:

```
Start: 1
Increment: 1
Maximum: 40
Reference Name: siteIndex
```

Now, to get the siteID from the result show in the corresponding HTTP Request, I edited the Name field of the HTTP Request to this:

```
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
```

But my HTTP Requests in the View Results Tree still end up showing as:

```
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
...
```

And not the actual siteID for the corresponding siteURL in the HTTP Request like:

```
21231
12315
21654
64574
76876
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this bit:

```
${siteID_"({siteIndex})"}
```

to

```
${__V(siteID_${siteIndex})}
```

Explanation:

As per [__V function documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V)

> For example, if one has variables A1,A2 and N=1:
>
> ${A1} - works OK
>
> ${A${N}} - does not work (nested variable reference)
>
> ${__V(A${N})} - works OK. A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

See [Using JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more examples on how to get things done with useful JMeter Functions.